# Prove that [−∞, 0) is isolated from the set (1,1/2, 1/3, 1/4... 1/n)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How to prove that [−∞, 0) is isolated from the set $S = \{\frac 1n \mid n\in\mathbb N: n\neq 0\}$ only using the concept of the punctured ball. $B_r'(x)=(x-r,x) \cup (x,x+r)$

I do understand the reasoning behind this. 0 is not an isolated point since the set is approaching 0 as n approaches infinity, and the punctured ball formed centered at 0 would necessarily contain numbers in Set S other than itself.

For any ball formed centered in [−∞, 0), the punctured ball won't contain numbers in set S,thus it's isolated from set s. But how can I prove this without using the concept of limit point, only using the definition of a punctured ball.

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't quite correct; one could define, say $B'_{-1}(2)$ which will contain elements of $S$. However for any value in $[-\infty, 0)$ you could define a punctured ball that contains only negative numbers, $S$ contains only positive numbers so the ball is disjoint from $S$. It has the flavor of a limit point argument but all it uses is the ball.

Comment: @DanishChef thank you so much!